# Select option from dropdown-element is not visible

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Please anyone can help me how to select options from the drop down if the element is not visible. 
Here is the html tag:

```
<select id="visualizationId" style="width: 120px; display: none;" name="visualization">
<option value="day">Day</option>
<option value="week">Week</option>
<option selected="" value="month">Month</option>
```

Am working on selenium webdriver. the below code is not working fine. Is there any sample code to select the invisible element.

```
Actions actions1 = new Actions(driver);
WebElement dBox1= ((new WebDriverWait(driver,60)).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("visualizationId"))));
selectByVisibleText("week");
actions1.moveToElement(dBox1);
actions1.click();
actions1.perform();
```

When using the below lines also am getting the error: Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with
Command duration or timeout: 32 millisecond

```
Select se=new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("visualizationId")));
se.selectByVisibleText("Week");
```

or

```
se.selectByValue("week");
```

Please see the html and there the element is not visible. Can any one suggest me how to make element visible and select the option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here, for selecting option, I'm trying to click on element using javascript(javascript because it allows you to interact with hidden elements). Following is the code, give a try. I'm not sure about the code and syntax(I'm not java guy), still you can use logic.

```
WebElement elementToSelect = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//select[@id='visualizationId']/option[text()='Day']")

JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", elementToSelect);
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the `=""`, just `selected` will work fine

Also, how are you supposed the select from a dropdown that isn't visible? There will be nothing to click

Comment: @Ajay, i tried with your code but am getting the following error:  Cannot locate element with text: week

Answer (score 0):

The selected attribute is a boolean attribute. The syntax is `<option selected>`. So Just try this without `""`

```
<option value="month" selected>Month</option>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
Select se=new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("visualizationId")));

se.selectByVisibleText("week")
```

Answer (score 0):

my bad its typo mistake misplaced "w" with "W"
 please try this

```
Select se=new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("visualizationId")));

se.selectByVisibleText("Week");
```

or

```
se.selectByValue("week");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can only interact with elements that are visible on the webpage. You can surely get the not visible element (or parts of it), but you can't do anything with it. If you want to interact with this Select element, you first need to make sure it's visible (display attribute of the Select element) so you can interact with it.